# What is the best/recommended CAPTCHA component for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, captcha

Does anyone have any recommendations for CAPTCHA components for use in ASP.NET projects?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've been using [recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) for a couple of sites with great success. I really recommend it.

There is a recaptcha control for asp.net [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet).

I've also used [this](http://www.mondor.org/captcha.aspx) captcha with success.

Comment: recaptcha is great, but their .Net control doesn't support the ValidationGroup property in .Net 2.0 +... Which means the control doesn't work at all on my site! I am looking for a way around that. Suggestions welcome :)

Comment: Alexn - thanks for the tip, this worked a treat for me.  Added the dll to the bin directory, added the reference and control to the page and away it went - piece of cake.

Comment: The plugin has been moved to https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.

Comment: Agree with @TimS - without ValidationGroup support you have to rely on Page.IsValid, so you don't know if it's the Catpcha field that's invalid or some other field - not very user-friendly.

Comment: here is new updated link https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/aspnet (for older versions, and a link to a new version)

Comment: Another disadvantage of recaptcha that it may be blocked in China by the Great Firewall

Comment: Website 'recaptcha.net' does not seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Before you evaluate any captcha solutions you should develop a clear profile of your users. Needless to say, any captcha solution is going to make your site harder to use. If your users are older with vision difficulties deciphering a captcha can be extremely difficult if not impossible. Random characters vs real words, may impact your users. Native language may affect user's perception of what the character represents (special characters).

No recommendations here, but knowing your users and what they will tolerate and or are capable of, should have a significant impact on your decision.

Comment: Good point. What would you then recommend other than using a captcha control given the scenarios you mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

How about [BotDetect](http://captcha.com/asp.net-captcha.html)?

The free version is available as well while they don't force your visitors to solve 2 captcha words.

Answer (score 2):

I would second the [Mondor's Captcha](http://mondor.org/captcha.aspx) mentioned in the first answer. Unlike the reCaptcha, it is fully independent, you don't make a call to other website. Also, it allows asking for solving a simple equation (like "5 + 3") and while bots would answer "5+3", human would answer 8. Also, unlike the reCaptcha, you can customize it as much as you want and include your own alphabet (Cyrillic, Arabic, Chinese - whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Recaptcha is a nice captcha to protect your forms if you want to take a dependency on Google.

Telerik has a great [ASP.Net captcha control](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/captcha.aspx) available that you should check out as well.

Comment: Recaptcha challenge letters are very very difficult to read. Visitors are not like to read such challenges

Comment: ... and if you're a spammer you don't like it much either

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the recaptcha, and it is great!

Here is the link for the ASP.NET plugin/wrapper:

[Using reCAPTCHA with ASP.NET](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet)

Comment: Recaptcha challenge letters are very very difficult to read. Visitors are not like to read such challenges

Comment: here is new updated link https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/aspnet (for older versions, and a link to a new version)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Picatcha](http://picatcha.com/) - pretty cool to use and looks easy to implement. Images vs text. Fairly customisable

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VB.NET as your base language (or even Classic ASP), I just found a great free CAPTCHA at [TipsTrips.org](http://www.tipstricks.org/).  You customize the CAPTCHA you want and then download the code.  The .NET download includes a ASHX handler file, two VB class files and an ASPX test page.

Comment: can we get the exact link please?

Comment: The exact link is http://www.tipstricks.org.  Which is the link I gave.

Comment: FYI, tipstricks is defunct and up for sale now.

Comment: If you're looking for vb.net, maybe try https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142624/Captcha-for-aspx-using-VB-NET