# whats mecanism for image captions 'human being '

Tags: asp.net, captcha

i need to how to implement image thast verify human benig as stack overflow
by insert and recieve image from database or whats?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best/recomended CAPTCHA component for ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696398/what-is-the-best-recomended-captcha-component-for-asp-net)

Comment: (that is, assuming the question is asking for an arrangement similar to what SO implements, as opposed to asking whether the human being is on SO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technology you need is called "Captcha". Google this, and you'll find several solutions for ASP.NET. Recaptcha is a good one IMHO.

Comment: any detailes  about this technology

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696398/what-is-the-best-recomended-captcha-component-for-asp-net