# How do i use captcha in the asp.net application for test input in simple way

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on asp.net web application where I need to use CAPTCHA to test input enter into textbox please let me know very simple way to implement CAPTCHA in asp.net.

Comment: what have you tried? there are numerous samples of how to integrate this - people wont just do your work for you

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696398/what-is-the-best-recomended-captcha-component-for-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Google search returns this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx

I'd recommend working through this tutorial, then if you have any problems, then ask questions. Like @Stack72 has stated, people won't just do it all for you, but will help if you get stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler (ashx).

Generate a random string, save that string into session, then use GDI+ to draw an image and sent it to response with content type is `image/...`

On captcha validation, load previous string from session and do the comparison.